# Is raw_input naturally a secure method for collecting user input?

Tags: python

Basically, would someone be able to compromise my program by entering code in for their raw_input?

```
i.e.
##instead of entering their name below, could they enter some compromising code?
name = raw_input('what is your name?: ')
```

Comment: Depends on what you do with the input, `eval()` for example, is not secure

Comment: Besides `eval`, there's SQL injection, `os.system`, and even `open` (if you don't want them to be able to, e.g., read `/etc/passwd` with your permissions) or `urlopen` (if you don't want them to trick you into parsing a malicious website instead of the one you intended). Any time you're using user input, you have to think through what you're doing with it, even if you _collected_ it safely.

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input` is safe in the immediate sense that this line:

```
name = raw_input('what is your name?: ')
```

By itself cannot trigger code injection. But after that, you could open up other vulnerabilities depending on what you do with the string. For example, if you use it for a database lookup, you still have to separately guard against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), usually by using [parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).